# Is there a way to mark "troughs" in a graph in R according to specific criteria?

Tags: r, intervals, region, rle

I have a data set which, when plotted, produces a graph that looks like this:

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keIp7.png)

The head of this data is:

```
> head(data_frame)
      score position
73860    10    43000
73859    10    43001
73858    10    43002
73857    10    43003
73856    10    43004
73855    10    43005
```

I've uploaded the whole file as a tab delimited text file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ujb_bHCPgAwepHj0J4E5eDMjgRCcAtAj/view?usp=sharing).

As you can see, the plot has regions which have a score of around 10, but there's one region in the middle that "dips". I would like to identify these dips.

Defining a dip as:

- Starting when the score is below 7
- Ending when the score rises to 7 or above **and stays at 7 or above for at least 500 positions**

I would like to identify all the regions which meet the above definition, and output their start and end positions. In this case that would only be the one region.

However, I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to do this. Looks like the `rle()` function could be useful, but I'm not too sure how to implement it.

Expected output for the data frame would be something like:

```
[1] 44561 46568
```

(I haven't actually checked that everything in between these would qualify under the definition, but from the plot this looks about right)

I would be very grateful for any suggestions!

Andrei

Answer (score 0):

So I've come up with one solution that uses a series of loops. I do realise this is inefficient, though, so if you have a better answer, please let me know.

```
results <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=1))
colnames(results) <- c("start","end")

state <- "out"
count <- 1
for (i in 1:dim(data_frame)[1]){
        print(i/dim(data_frame)[1])
        if (data_frame[i,3] < 7 & state=="out") {
                results[count,1] <- data_frame[i,2]
                state <- "in"
                next
        }
        if (data_frame[i,3] >= 7 & state=="in") {
                if ((i+500)>dim(data_frame)[1]){
                        results[count,2] <- data_frame[dim(data_frame)[1],2]
                        state <- "out"
                        break
                }
                if (any(data_frame[(i+1):(i+500),3] < 7)) {
                        next
                } else {
                        results[count,2] <- data_frame[i-1,2]
                        count <- count+1
                        state <- "out"
                        next
                }
        }
        if ((i+500)>dim(data_frame)[1] & state == "out") {
                break
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is a `tidyverse` solution and uses `rle` as OP suggested...

```
below7 <- data_frame$score < 7
x <- rle(below7)
runs <- tibble(
          RunLength=x$lengths, 
          Below7=x$values,
          RunStart=df$position[1]
        ) %>% 
        mutate(
          RunStart=ifelse(
                     row_number() == 1, 
                     data_frame$position[1], 
                     data_frame$position[1] + cumsum(RunLength)-RunLength+1
          ),
          RunEnd=RunStart + RunLength-1,
          Dip=Below7,
          Dip=Dip | Below7 | (!Below7 & RunLength < 500)
        )
as.data.frame(runs)
```

Giving

```
   RunLength Below7 RunStart RunEnd   Dip
1       1393  FALSE    43000  44392 FALSE
2         84   TRUE    44394  44477  TRUE
3         84  FALSE    44478  44561  TRUE
...
19        60  FALSE    46338  46397  TRUE
20       171   TRUE    46398  46568  TRUE
21      2433  FALSE    46569  49001 FALSE
```

So to get OP's final answer

```
runs %>% 
  filter(Dip) %>% 
  summarise(
    DipStart=min(RunStart), 
    DipEnd=max(RunEnd)
  )
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  DipStart DipEnd
     <dbl>  <dbl>
1    44394  46568
```

If the original data.frame might contain more than one dip, you'd have to do a little more work when creating the `runs` tibble:  having indentified each individual run, you'd need to create an additional column, `DipIndex` say, which indexed each individual Dip.